# Click to minimize inconsistent in xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04

I have a panel with a the list of windows.  For some programs, clicking on their window button on the panel minimizes the window.  (Firefox acts this way).  Others, clicking does nothing.

How do I make it to that the are consistent?  (I'd prefer the click minimizes the window, but could get by without that.  But having different results for different windows is driving me nuts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this too on upgrading Xubuntu. The windows would minimise on the first ever click on the panel button, but then refuse to from then on. I solved it by deleting `.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml` - there's obviously some conflicting setting in there from the previous version of xfce. This means you will lose your xfwm settings, but they shouldn't be too hard to re-create.

Edit: Just done some more tests, it seems to be that having "focus follows mouse" rather than "click to focus", is what causes the problem :/ [relevant launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfwm4/+bug/1292122)

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Hopefully they get that fixed soon